# jeditable - disable it at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

is it possible to disable jeditable for a table at runtime?

The case:

I got different steps for the User, the table is always visible, but should be just in one single step editable. The user can switch the steps as he likes.

I found nothing about that in the jeditable docs.

I tryed to remove the triggering class, but after initialization, it does not effect the "editability" ("editability" is more german than english, but I guess you understand me ;)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example. I hope can help you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php";, {
         indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
         type : "textarea",
         submit : "OK"
     }, function(value, settings) {
         $(this).unbind(settings.event);
     });
});
```

From this link [jEditable: how to remove behaviour](http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg19936.html) answered by plugin's author

Comment: Thx, "unbind" was the right hint :). In my case (I need to set all affected cells with one trigger):  >> $('.theClassName').unbind('click.editable');  << works fine.I'm happy :).

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the simplest way is:

```
jQuery(".editable").editable('disable');
```

and if you need to enable it back

```
jQuery(".editable").editable('enable');
```